# Open and read spectral library as array in Python?

Tags: python, envi, array

I'm creating a spectral library in envi and I need to read this as an as array in python. I'm trying to use pysptools (pysptools.classification.SAM) package but i don't understand how to do this from the documentation.

```
sam.classify(M, E, threshold=0.1, mask=None)

Parameters: 
M – numpy array A HSI cube (m x n x p).
E – numpy array A spectral library (N x p).
```

How to pass parameter E (I have spectral library created in ENVI)?
Please Provide example if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm reading ENVI spectral libraries using `spectral`

```
import spectral as sp1
import pandas as pd
SpecLib = sp1.envi.open('path to spectral library')
SpecLib_df = pd.DataFrame(index=SpecLib.names, data= SpecLib.spectra, columns=SpecLib.bands.centers)
```

Note that the path to your SpecLib should contain the folder+file+'hdr', for example:

```
c:\SpecLibs\example.hdr
```